# How to pass a function reference, instead of the function itself?

Tags: pointers, clojure, reference

Let us say we define the function `my-function` that will print `"message1"`.
Next at the repl we define this atom which uses that function.

```
(def key-func (atom {:func my-function}))
```

After that I update the function `my-function` to print `"message2"`.
Now when I run `((:func @key-func))` it prints `"message1"`. I end up having to reload the atom. This would lead me to believe that `{:func my-function}` is not pairing a reference to the actual function with `:func` rather it is passing a copy of what the function is at that time. So, is it possible to pass a function pointer rather than a copy?

TLDR;

```
(defn my-func [] (print "message1"))
(def key-func (atom {:func my-func}))
(defn my-func [] (print "message2"))
((:func @key-func)) ;prints message1 instead of message2
```

Comment: I think I am using the terms pointer and reference correctly, but if I am not please correct me and I will fix the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

See this question: [When to use a Var instead of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function/39550785)

### Longer Answer

You are using the atom in a non-standard way.  I think the following is closer to what you want:

```
(defn f1 [] "#1")
(defn f2 [] "#2")


(def my-fn (atom f1))
(println :1 (@my-fn))
(reset! my-fn f2)
(println :2 (@my-fn))
```

Generates:

```
:1 #1
:2 #2
```

### Longest Version

This example shows the difference between copying a function vs copying the var that points to the function:

```
; This will not work, since his-fn saves a ref to the 
; immutible "All yours baby!" function
(newline)
(println "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
(defn your-fn [] (println "All yours baby!"))
(your-fn)  ;=> "All yours baby!"
(def  his-fn your-fn)
(his-fn)   ;=> "All yours baby!"
(defn your-fn [] (println "And it still is!"))
(his-fn)   ;=> "All yours baby!"

; This will work, since both his-fn and her-fn save a reference 
; to the var `your-fn`, which in turn points to first to 
; one function and then to a second function.
(newline)
(println "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
(defn your-fn [] (println "All yours baby!"))
(your-fn)
(def  his-fn (var your-fn))
(def  her-fn    #'your-fn)
(his-fn) 
(her-fn) 
; change what var "your-fn" points to
(defn your-fn [] (println "And now you belong to me..."))
(his-fn) 
(her-fn)
```

With results:

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;=> All yours baby!
;=> All yours baby!
;=> All yours baby!

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;=> All yours baby!
;=> All yours baby!
;=> All yours baby!
;=> And now you belong to me...
;=> And now you belong to me...
```

### Warning

Having shown how vars behave, please remember it is not good to redefine top-level forms like `(def ...)` and `(defn ...)`.  It is usually best to use an atom, or a local var to hold changing values.

Comment: In response to warning: I understand that it is bad practice to redefine top level forms. My case is  development where these top-level forms that typically wouldn't change are being reloaded frequently for testing purposes. I wanted the updated functions to be reflected in the state atom which is not reloaded.