# What is the difference between with-redefs and with-redefs-fn in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, mocking, clojurescript

I would like to understand difference between `with-redefs` and `with-redefs-fn`.

Concrete examples would be great to understand the fns behaviours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're basically the same, the main difference is that `with-redefs` lets you write out the body explicitly (like in a `let`), while `with-redefs-fn` requires a function as the argument, so you may need to wrap what you want in a lambda. Additionally, `with-redefs` lets you provide bindings using a vector (again, like `let`), while `with-redefs-fn` wants a map. I'd argue that both of these differences are just superficial.

e.g.

```
(with-redefs [http/post (fn [url] {:body "Goodbye world"})]
  (is (= {:body "Goodbye world"} (http/post "http://service.com/greet"))))
```

vs

```
(with-redefs-fn {#'http/post (fn [url] {:body "Goodbye world"})}
      (fn [] (is (= {:body "Goodbye world"} (http/post "http://service.com/greet")))))
```

In fact, `with-redefs` is defined in terms of `with-redefs-fn`, and basically just wraps the body in an anonymous function before passing everything to `with-redefs-fn`: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/e3c4d2e8c7538cfda40accd5c410a584495cb357/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7404

Answer (score 7):

I would ignore `with-redefs-fn` and use only `with-redefs` since it is simpler and has the same abilities. Also, beware that the notation `#'http/post` requires you to use the var for `http/post`, not the function itself.

For a description of how a Clojure `var` works, please see this question:  [When to use a Var instead of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function/39550785)   It is similar to a C pointer.

In clojure, when you see `foo`, it is a symbol. When you see `#'foo`, it is a shortcut for `(var foo)` which is a "special form" (i.e. a Clojure built-in, not a regular function), which returns the `var` that `foo` points to.  The `var` in turn points the the value of `foo`.