# Clojure - To pass a function as a var 'vs' To call a function from within the other function?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I was just wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages to choose one over the other, or if it is purely just a design choice for a project's scope/workflow?

Scenario 1 : Using var and eval

```
 (defn fun1 [x] (prn (* x x)))
 (defn fun2 [y] (#'fun1 y))
 (eval (fun2 2))
 4
 nil
```

Scenario 2 : Creating a sequential chaining of function calls

```
(defn fun1 [x] (prn (* x x)))
(defn fun3 [y] (fun1 y))
(fun3 2)
4
nil
```

I really appreciate your responses, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note `eval` is a function so `(eval (fun2 2))` calls `(fun2 2)` and then `eval` on the result i.e. `(eval 4)` so there's no reason to prefer that approach. Calling functions via the var directly is also unnecessary since symbols are evaluted to the value of the corresponding var.

Comment: @Lee got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scenario 1, I believe you meant to do this:

```
(defn fun1 [x] (prn (* x x)))
(defn fun2 [y] (#'fun1 y))
(fun2 2)
```

It is almost never necessary (nor desirable) to use `eval`

For more detail on the difference between these Scenario 1 & 2, please [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function/39550785#39550785).