# How to define default component in Reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to create SPA application with Reagent. How I can define default page/component? As I understand it, I should save current page in state atom. But I can't define it if I change state in home page.
For example, in this code `home` cannot be resolved (row 1):

```clj
(defonce app-state (atom {:current-page (home)}))

(defn second-page []
  [:p 2])

(defn home []
  [:div
   [:p 1]
   [:input {:type "button" :value "Click!"
            :on-click #(swap! app-state second-page)}]])

(defn hello-world []
  [:div
   [:input {:type "button" :value "Home" :on-click #(swap! app-state home)}]
   (:current-page @app-state)
   [:h3 "footer"]])

(reagent/render-component [hello-world]
                          (. js/document (getElementById "app")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can solve this issue. One approach would be to create a map called pages like so

```
(def pages {:home home
            :second second-page
            ....}
```

and then use the key name in the state atom i.e.

```
(defonce app-state (atom {:current-page :home})
```

Because you are just storing a keyword, there is no need for forward delarations as keywords evaluate to themselves. Then in your code, you would use the value for  :current-page to lookup the compoonent from the pages map

```
defn hello-world []
  [:div
   [:input {:type "button" :value "Home" :on-click #(swap! app-state home)}]
   ((:current-page @app-state) pages)
   [:h3 "footer"]])
```

You may also find things like [secretary](https://github.com/clj-commons/secretary) useful as an example of one way to generalise this sort of idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `declare` to put placeholders for `home` and `second-page` before the atom:

```
(declare home second-page)

(defonce app-state (atom {:current-page home}))
```

Be sure to always keep a browser tab open to [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function/39550785#39550785) for more details on the workings of Clojure's `var` feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in your case `app-state` is undefined in line `:on-click #(swap! app-state second-page)}]`. Can you give me please a example how I can use `declare` for this problem? I should use `(declare app-state)` or `(declare home)`?