# why the 2 way indirection of symbol -> var -> value

Tags: clojure

Why does clojure have symbols mapped to vars, instead they being mapped directly to values ? What is the idea behind the 2 way indirection of symbol resolving to a var, and a var referencing a value ?

What is var actually, is it just a memory reference, or a java class which does much more ?

The docs says that this is needed so that the values can be redefined, however why cant they redefined if there was no 2 way indirection ?

Comment: Yes [Var](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/653b8465845a78ef7543e0a250078eea2d56b659/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java) is implemented as a java class and is used for thread bindings, metadata, validation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a detailed description of the Clojure `var` mechanism here:  [When to use a Var instead of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function/39550785#39550785)

Since Clojure data is immutable, you need an indirection mechanism like a `var` or `atom` to allow for "change".  This is a bit like having a variable `name` in Java, which is actually a pointer to a string like `Fred`.  Later, you may reassign `name` to point to a different string `Barney`.