# Clojure: Convert a string to a function

Tags: clojure

The following works:

```clj
((resolve (symbol "first")) [1 2 3])
;; => 1
```

Why is it wrong to think that,

```clj
((read-string "first") [1 2 3])
;; => nil
```

should work, but it doesn't? (I get `nil`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value from `(resolve (symbol "first"))` is probably the Var `clojure.core/first` which gets applied to the arguments.

The return value from `(read-string "first")` is the symbol `first` which also gets applied to the arguments. But using a symbol as a function has a different meaning. The argument is expected to be a map and the returned value is the equivalent of doing `(get a-map the-symbol)`.

Any type that implements the `clojure.lang.IFn` can be in the function position. The reason why using a symbol as a function with a vector argument returns `nil` instead of failing, lies in the [implementation details of `IFn` for the `Symbol`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L127) type (in this particular case for the arity 1):

```java
public Object invoke(Object obj) {
    return RT.get(obj, this);
}
```

[`RT.get()`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L758) checks if `obj` implements `ILookup` and calls `ILookup.valAt()` if it does. Clojure vectors do implement `ILookup` but they [expect an integer as the provided key and return `nil` for anything else](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java#L360).

```java
public Object valAt(Object key, Object notFound){
    if(Util.isInteger(key))
        {
        int i = ((Number) key).intValue();
        if(i >= 0 && i < count())
            return nth(i);
        }
    return notFound;
}

public Object valAt(Object key){
    return valAt(key, null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Juan is correct:

```
(resolve (symbol "first"))    => <#clojure.lang.Var #'clojure.core/first>
(read-string "first")         => <#clojure.lang.Symbol first>
```

We can verify:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [first-var (var clojure.core/first)
        first-sym (symbol "first")]
    (is= 1   (first-var [1 2 3])) ; automatically converted from a var => funciton by Clojure
    (is= nil (first-sym [1 2 3]))))
```

Please also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function) for more information on the double-indirection of a Clojure Var object.