# How to run library's `main` with Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I had used some library, let's say it is Clojure itself (which is *always* added to `project.clj`). Clojure provides `clj` CLI tool (which is `src/cli/clojure/main.clj`, but nevermind). How to use it with `lein`? I mean, is there any command/plugin/technique which will allow me to use library's `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Var` in every namespace is equal in the eyes of Clojure.  From your code, just execute like:

```clj
   (some.awesome.lib/-main ...)
```

or whatever the fully-qualified symbol pointing to the `Var` in question.

For further details, please see this question:

- [When to use a Var instead of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function)

---

**Also**

See the output of

```
> lein help run
```

Using lein, you can type

```
lein run -m my.awesome.proj/some-fn
```

or

```
lein run -m some.awesome.lib/-main
```

since to Clojure `some.awesome.lib/-main` is no different than any other function (the hyphen prefix on `-main` is just a convention and makes no difference to the Clojure compiler).

You can also set up `project.clj` to automatically call any function of your choosing when you type `lein run` by adding:

```
:main some.awesome.lib/-main
```

Comment: I don't want to execute it in my code, but I do want to execute it with `lein` tool.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know *how* I read help for `run` sub-command, but I didn't see the `-m` option. This is what exactly I wanted.

Comment: `lein run some.awesome.lib` should work for `-main` in `some.awesome.lib`?

Comment: Yeah, there's no "in your project" vs "not in your project" distinction. You can confirm this without even needing a dependency: `lein run -m clojure.main` works fine, and clojure.main certainly isn't in my project.

Comment: Ya know, I tested that and must have made a mistake!  Fixed.