# What is the meaning of # in front of Clojure symbol?

Tags: clojure

When I declare a global `Var` like:

```
(def x 100)
```

I get the following output -

```
=> #'tutorial.core/x
```

I can understand that the `'tutorial.core/x` is a symbol here, but what is the meaning of `#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "pound-quote" or `#'` is a reader macro. That is, it is shorthand for typing

```
(var tutorial.core/x)
```

or just

```
(var x)   ; in the same namespace
```

You can find [more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550513/when-to-use-a-var-instead-of-a-function).